# ktor websocket install error on Android device

Tags: android, websocket, ktor

I am trying to run trivial chat sample on an Android device with ktor websocket but it does not work well.
I have an error when installing websocket server in MainActivity

Here is build.gradle for ktor websocket

```
//this is for project
ext.ktor_version = '1.2.5'
maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }

//this is for app
 packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }

    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-websockets:$ktor_version"
```

And Here is code for MainActivity

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.features.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.CloseReason
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.Frame
import io.ktor.http.content.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.sessions.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.*
import java.time.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        install(WebSockets) {
            pingPeriod = Duration.ofSeconds(60) // Disabled (null) by default
            timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(15)
            maxFrameSize = Long.MAX_VALUE // Disabled (max value). The connection will be closed if surpassed this length.
            masking = false
        }
    }
}
```

When I build this code on Android Studio, the error is occurred

```
public fun <P : Pipeline<*, ApplicationCall>, B : Any, F : Any> ???.install(feature: ApplicationFeature<???, WebSockets.WebSocketOptions, WebSockets>, configure: WebSockets.WebSocketOptions.() -> Unit = ...): WebSockets defined in io.ktor.application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Websockets](https://ktor.io/servers/features/websockets.html#artifact-87) is one of the server [features](https://ktor.io/servers/index.html#features) that you can plug into an application, so the context for the `install` call should be a Ktor application, not an Android `Activity`. I recommend you to look at [Hello world](https://ktor.io/quickstart/#hello-world) example. Here is your sample code modified:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.websocket.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import java.time.Duration
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        embeddedServer(Netty, 4444) {
            install(WebSockets) {
                pingPeriod = Duration.ofSeconds(60) // Disabled (null) by default
                timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(15)
                maxFrameSize = Long.MAX_VALUE // Disabled (max value). The connection will be closed if surpassed this length.
                masking = false
            }
            routing {
                webSocket("/") {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }
}
```

You need to add the following dependencies to make this sample work:

```
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3" // for logging
```

Comment: It works! But unfortunately, only websocket connection is working well. Rounting seem to be not worked. When I checked browser with js, echo message is not replied after connecting to websocket server in Android device. Do you know why?

Comment: Here is rounting code
`routing {  webSocket("/") { println("webSocket OK") while (true) {  val frame = incoming.receive()  when (frame) {  is Frame.Text -> {  val text = frame.readText() outgoing.send(Frame.Text(text)) }  }  }  }`

Comment: Here is js code
`<script type = "text/javascript">  function startWebSocket() {  if ("WebSocket" in window) { var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.7:4444"); ws.onopen = function() { ws.send("Hello");  alert("Send message to Server(Hello)."); };  ws.onmessage = function (evt) {  var msg = evt.data;   alert("Message is received(" + msg + ")");  }; ws.onclose = function() { alert("WebSocket is closed.");  };  } else {  alert("Your browser does not support WebSocket !!!");  }   }  </script>`

Comment: Please try code example from [here](https://ktor.io/servers/features/websockets.html#actor). Also, try specifying the IP address `127.0.0.1` (if you are testing it in a browser from a device or an emulator) instead of `192.168.0.7`. In your code example, I don't see you calling `startWebSocket` function, so that could be a problem too.

Comment: Can you please share your app? I want to build chat with ktor but nothing even compiles

Comment: @NurseyitTursunkulov please have a look at the chat sample application https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/master/generic/samples/chat

Comment: @AlekseiTirman could you please explain how connect android app to websocket sample?

Comment: @seans My kotlin version is 1.4.10 and ktor version is 2.1.1. I am facing build failed in android studio but no errors shown. Can you pls help ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell your current Kotlin version and Gradle version being used? If Kotlin version is less than 1.4 then I would suggest trying to add `-jvm` or `-android` to ktor dependency names in your build.gradle.

Comment: My Kotlin version is '1.3.61' but I don't know how add `-android` dependency in build.gradle.
When I change build.gradle as `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61' -android`, build error is happened. `Could not get unknown property 'android' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.`